Why was Adam told not to eat from the tree?
We read in Genesis, "The Lord God planted a garden in Eden, in the east, and there He placed the man He had formed. The Lord God caused to grow out of the ground every tree pleasing in appearance and good for food, including the tree of life in the middle of the garden, as well as the tree of the knowledge of good and evil." (Genesis 2:8-9) Why was this tree there if Adam was not supposed to eat from it? How did this tree that came from the ground contain the knowledge of good and evil?

We are not told so we do not know.

@Dottan, thank you for your honesty. That is exactly what I come up with.

We are told! God wanted them to avoid death, so He gave them a ‘heads up’. God always provides a choice, if He wants us to choose, we have to have both options clearly available.


God created everything perfect
The creation narrative emphasizes that God saw everything He had made as “very good” (Gen. 1:31). This includes the Garden of Eden and its trees, which were part of a perfect environment designed to enable humanity to fulfill its divine purpose. The Tree of Life, located at the garden’s center, symbolized eternal life in communion with God. It was central to human existence, signifying dependence on God as the ultimate source of life and blessing.

The Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil, in contrast, was not central. Its placement “in the garden” suggests it was peripheral, existing not to harm but as a test of Adam’s and Eve’s obedience and trust in God’s word.

Adam’s mission: to cultivate and guard the garden
Adam was tasked with “cultivating and keeping” the garden (Gen. 2:15). The Hebrew verbs `abad (עָבַד, “to cultivate”) and shamar (שָׁמַר, “to guard”) carry priestly undertones, implying that Adam’s role extended beyond physical labor to spiritual stewardship. His duty to "guard" (shamar) included protecting the sanctity of the garden and maintaining God’s order.

The presence of the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil offered Adam an opportunity to exercise free will by obeying God’s command. This prohibition was not arbitrary; it was a call to trust and depend on God rather than seeking autonomy through disobedience.

Eve as a suitable helper
Eve was created as a “helper fit for” Adam (Gen. 2:18). The Hebrew phrase `ezer kenegdo (עֵזֶר כְּנֶגְדּוֹ) describes a counterpart who complemented Adam in his mission. In their state of perfection, Eve had no innate inclination to deceive or betray. However, because the command not to eat from the forbidden tree was given directly to Adam before Eve’s creation (Gen. 2:16-18), Eve depended on Adam’s transmission of the divine instruction.

This indirect knowledge made her more vulnerable to the serpent’s deception, which exploited her lack of direct awareness of God’s command.

The serpent’s theological debate with Eve
The serpent, described as “crafty” (Gen. 3:1), strategically engaged Eve in a theological debate. It began by questioning God’s command: “Did God actually say...?” (Gen. 3:1). This subtle distortion planted doubt in Eve’s mind and reframed the divine command in a way that shifted the focus from trust in God to self-reliance.

Eve responded by adding a prohibition God had not given: “You shall not eat of it, neither shall you touch it” (Gen. 3:3). This misrepresentation highlights how Eve, lacking firsthand knowledge of the command, had already begun to misunderstand God’s words. The serpent exploited this confusion to shift Eve’s attention from the Tree of Life, at the garden’s center, to the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil, now reframed as desirable and essential for wisdom (Gen. 3:6).

The Tree of Life in the midst of the garden
The Tree of Life is consistently described as being “in the midst of the garden” (Gen. 2:9; 3:22). Its central location signifies its importance as the source of eternal life and communion with God. Notably, God never prohibited Adam or Eve from eating from this tree before the Fall. This suggests that eternal life was accessible to them as long as they remained obedient and maintained their relationship with God.

However, Eve, misled by the serpent’s manipulation, overlooked the Tree of Life and focused instead on the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil. The serpent’s strategy effectively redirected her attention away from God’s provision to a counterfeit source of fulfillment.

The Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil in the garden
Unlike the Tree of Life, the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil is not described as central but as being “in the garden.” Its peripheral placement reinforces its role as a test of obedience rather than a source of sustenance. By design, it was meant to remain secondary to the Tree of Life.

Eve’s confusion regarding the tree’s location and purpose, coupled with her misinterpretation of God’s command, reveals how the serpent successfully sowed doubt and reoriented her focus toward disobedience.

Adam’s culpability
Unlike Eve, Adam was not deceived by the serpent (1 Tim. 2:14). He knew the command directly from God and understood the distinction between the Tree of Life and the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil. Yet, when Eve offered him the fruit, he chose to eat, fully aware of the consequences. His failure to guard the garden and his wife, as well as his willful disobedience, highlights a lapse in his priestly role as protector of God’s order.

Conclusion
Adam was prohibited from eating from the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil to affirm his dependence on God and his obedience to divine authority. The Tree of Life, located at the garden’s center, symbolized the eternal life and communion with God available to humanity. The serpent’s cunning manipulation led Eve to misunderstand the command and shift her focus from God’s provision to a false promise of wisdom. Adam, though not deceived, failed to fulfill his role as guardian and chose disobedience, leading to humanity’s estrangement from the divine life offered through the Tree of Life. This narrative underscores the danger of abandoning God’s truth for distorted interpretations and misplaced priorities.

Why did I have a feeling of reading an answer generated by AI...?

I have already discussed this in this forum... AI always provides conventional answers... Try generating this same answer, in which the serpent swapped the position of the trees in Eve's mind—it won't work...

@Betho's - How does 'very good' equate to 'perfection'? Why would you draw that automatic conclusion?

The phrase "very good" in Genesis 1:31 reflects God's evaluation that creation perfectly fulfilled its intended purpose. In the Hebrew context, "good" (tov) implies not just moral quality but functional completeness. Thus, "very good" signifies everything was in perfect harmony, fully aligned with God's will, justifying its interpretation as perfection in a biblical sense.

'The tree of the knowledge of good and evil - thou dost not eat of it.' Is the original, see Young's Literal Bible.
Humanity does not 'eat' (partake in order to sustain life) of it. It is not food. It will not nourish. It will neither give nor sustain life.
Rather, it will be fatal.
It is not food. It cannot be digested. It will kill you.
Knowledge is not what humanity needs. We need life. We have natural life, breath in the nostrils, but we have not spiritual life by creation.
Life is given to humanity by a new birth, by an inward Spirit, by a gift. And it is given through word.
There was in the garden, in the midst, in the midst of Adam and Eve, between them, the word of life.
This was the word of life : 'The tree of the knowledge of good and evil - thou dost not eat of it'.
God gave everything - dominion over all. There was but one restriction. That tree. It will kill you. Thou dost not eat of it. It is fatal.
Hear this word of life that was in the midst. Another 'tree' with branches, branching out. Grasp that one truth (about the other tree) and one will see more.
To him that hath shall be given.
Hear this word of life  . . . .  and live.

Nigel J- It says in Genesis 2:8-9, "The Lord God caused to grow out of the ground (every tree) pleasing in appearance and (good) for food, (including) the tree of life in the middle of the garden, as well as the tree of the knowledge of good and evil." Apparently, the tree was good for food. What is interesting is no one catches this. What's also interesting is, what the serpent said would happen to Eve. Happened! I truly believe there are missing pieces to the puzzle and we just don't know why.

@RomanDeLeon You misquote the scripture. The original does not place the tree of knowledge of good and evil in the garden at all. Nor is it one of the 'good for food' trees. Inaccuracy in the word led Eve astray. And inaccuracy will lead all astray without paying attention to the detail. I suggest you look at Robert Young's Literal Translation for accuracy.

Nigel J- Robert Young has mislead you ! Those are scripture quotes from masoretic text. Read, 2:9       וַיַּצְמַח יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים מִן־הָאֲדָמָה כָּל־עֵץ נֶחְמָד
לְמַרְאֶה וְטוֹב לְמַאֲכָל וְעֵץ הַחַיִּים בְּתוֹךְ הַגָּן וְעֵץ
הַדַּעַת טוֹב וָרָע׃

Nigel J- One cannot twist the scripture to fit ones own belief.

Nigel J- If you would prefer Greek. LXX Septaugint, καὶ ἐξανέτειλεν ὁ θεὸς ἔτι ἐκ τῆς γῆς πᾶν ξύλον ὡραῖον εἰς ὅρασιν καὶ καλὸν εἰς βρῶσιν καὶ τὸ ξύλον τῆς ζωῆς ἐν μέσῳ τῷ παραδείσῳ καὶ τὸ ξύλον τοῦ εἰδέναι γνωστὸν καλοῦ καὶ πονηροῦ

Nigel J- Here is your Young's translation, "and Jehovah God causeth to sprout from the ground every tree desirable for appearance, and (good for food), and the tree of life in the midst of the garden, and the tree of knowledge of good and evil.

Indeed. The tree of knowledge of good and evil is not said to be in the garden. . . . ..  and the tree etc. Why would I not want to use the Masoretic text ? What other text are you advocating ?

Nigel J- The quotes I shared were from the Masoretic text, is what I was pointing out to you. Therefore, how could I misquote the Scripture?

There are several possible answers. No single answer is universally accepted.

It was predestined. This viewpoint is held by many Christians. God planned even before the creation to send Jesus Christ to die for mankind's sins. This plan could not be fulfilled if Adam and Eve did not disobey the Commandment. It was all part of God's plan. (1 Pt. 1:18-20)

To overcome the tendency to evil. This is a typical Jewish answer. Humans were created by God with a tendency toward self-centeredness and evil, called the yetzer harah. God gave Adam the Commandment to guide him to resist this tendency.

We are not told so we do not know. The Bible does not tell us why God gave Adam the commandment or why God placed the this particular tree in the Garden. We should simply accept the fact on faith.

The Commandment was temporary. This view holds that Adam and Eve were not yet mature and needed the refrain from "eating the fruit" until they were ready to become parents. (This viewpoint implies that eating the fruit was symbolic of sexual union.)



I don't think God would intentionally setup mankind to fail. The thought to overcome the tendency to evil would have been a failure as well. What draws my attention is that after they ate from the tree, "The Lord God said, “Since man has become like one of Us, knowing good and evil, he must not reach out, take from the tree of life, eat, and live forever.” Now, they have become like God and are not to touch the tree of life. Does this not catch anyones attention?

@RomanDeLeon God didn’t set them up to fail, He offered both choices, as He always does, knowing that they would be deceived. For the fight is against spiritual powers, not logic or personal will.

From Bible study and Worship Service, I have learned that there was a very specific reason God had to put the tree of the knowledge of good and evil there. It was to teach Adam and Eve what was wrong and what was right. What was good/evil. But, the fruit was like a test to see if they would truly respect and obey God, or become proud and disobey God. It would've been more dangerous to not have this fruit because perhaps they would not respect God and turn their backs on Him. There had to be some negative consequence in their disobedience that backfired at them if they were to disobey. It showed that God is God and we need to respect that. That was the one command that was given to them, so it should've been easy enough to obey; however, they sinned and consequences ensued.

Welcome, of course, God put the serpent there too as an alternative to Him. You are right, He always provides a choice.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

There are two accounts of the creation of Adam in Genesis.
Genesis 1
"26 And God saith, `Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our likeness, and let them rule over fish of the sea, and over fowl of the heavens, and over cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that is creeping on the earth.'
27 And God prepareth the man in His image; in the image of God He prepared him, a male and a female He prepared them.
28 And God blessed them, and God saith to them, `Be fruitful, and multiply, and fill the earth, and subdue it, and rule over fish of the sea, and over fowl of the heavens, and over every living thing that is creeping upon the earth."
This is when the unitary soul (male and female) of Adam was created, and became the ruler of the earth. Also, all souls of all humans were inside Adam when he was created. (1 Corinthians 15:22)
Adam was the only begotten son of God, since he was directly created by God.
Luke 3:38 "the son of Enosh, the son of Seth, the son of Adam, the son of God."
Then comes along another account of the creation of Adam in Genesis 2.
"7 And Jehovah God formeth the man -- dust from the ground, and breatheth into his nostrils breath of life, and the man becometh a living creature.
8 And Jehovah God planteth a garden in Eden, at the east, and He setteth there the man whom He hath formed;"
The reason there are two accounts is because something happened between Genesis 1 and Genesis 2, which was the rebellion of Adam in the Heavenly Garden of Eden and is described by Ezekiel 28:11-19.
God then formed a body for Adam and placed him in the Earthly Garden of Eden.  Adam's body, since it was bound to the earth and couldn't die, kept him from ascending to Heaven.
In order for Adam to once again be able to ascend to Heaven, he would have to prove his obedience to God.  So, God put the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil in the garden to test Adam's obedience.
One can deduce that the test of the Tree is in regard to the rulership of God because Adam is listening to the Nachash when it is talking to Eve. ("She also gave some to her husband, who was with her"), and the Nachash says in Genesis 3:5 “For God knows that when you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God..."
It is what Adam wanted in the first rebellion, "to be like God". Adam thinks that by eating the fruit he will be able to shed the earthly body and once again be able to ascend to the heavenly Eden. He believes the lie and is disobedient again, not realizing that death means mortality and an endless cycle of reincarnation within the mortal sphere, never being able to attain the spiritual body that Heaven requires.
That is why the Apostle Paul says "Jesus, being in the form of God, humbled Himself and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross." Jesus' obedience reverses Adam's disobedience in the Garden.
Jesus being in the form of God means he was Adam (the son of God) reversing his original sin.  The first Adam and the last Adam are the same Adam.  Resurrection means getting back the spiritual body that can now enter Heaven and effectively stops reincarnation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Taking a cue from point 4 of Dan Fefferman's answer, I wish to think in terms of pure biological aspects of the taboo and the disobedience.When Adam and Eve were created , their brains were in a blissful state like those of children. The wiring of their brain cells was meant only for survival, which was not a problem with plenty of food and other living being for company. The forbidden fruit had some properties that redefined blood supply to the brain and enhanced neuron network. The result: good and bad effects of reasoning power, including the discovery of their sexuality.Look at how they find out their nakedness after  eating the fruit.
Also consider the punishment given to Eve: delivery pangs ! Does it commensurate with the act of eating a forbidden fruit ? ( Interestingly, human beings are perhaps the only species which get delivery pangs to such a high degree,  mainly because  of the peculiar pelvic structure, which narrowed to enable us walk straight ).
With the creation of progeny , some human beings had to die in order to make way for the new generation. The more the new birth, the more the deaths . Well, Adam was lucky to live on for 930 years , and we are not told how long the Great Grandma Eve lived.
